# Turn Off - “prevent this page from creating additional dialogs”

Tags: javascript, firefox

How do I turn off the Firefox feature “prevent this page from creating additional dialogs”?

I get this problem, when I open more than one confirm box(dialog).

Is it possible to prevent this feature via Javascript?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to undo the checkbox - I want alerts back! How would I do THAT?

Comment: I found the solution for my question: Close and open the tab again. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a browser feature and is intended to protect the user. If you could turn it off, all those sites spamming users with dialogs would have a way to stop it.

So in short, no.

Make your application work with it, instead of against it. Don't rely on dialogs/confirmations too much, rather have a `modal-box` ask the questions; it is pretty too :)

Answer (score 9):

Open `about:config` then change the pref `dom.successive_dialog_time_limit`

Of course this only works for your own browser, you can't change it for other people.

Comment: Is there any other way to change the setting via script

Comment: There is no way to change the setting via script

Comment: In particular, you have to set the time limit to 0, see https://uweschmelzer.wordpress.com/2012/04/18/how-to-turn-off-the-prevent-page-from-creating-additional-dialogs/ for complete description.

Comment: this works in firefox, but how can I do same in Google Chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no way to disable it. Alert boxes are obtrusive, and at least in Firefox - can steal focus even from other tabs.

A simple workaround is to use an HTML based [modal dialog](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20modal) - this will also give you full control over the dialog, its design (across browsers and operating systems), its buttons, behavior of the rest of the page, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Finally the issue is solved :) , developer need some attention before calling any alert or confirm  messages in chrome or firefox. 
The alert or confirm box will display 1.5 sec delay.

```
    function chromeTimeDelay(){
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > 0){
            var d =e = new Date();
            while(d.getTime()<(e.getTime()+1500)){
            d = new Date();
            }
        }
    }



    function dontdisplaycheckbox(){
      for(var i=0;i<=10;i++){
      chromeTimeDelay();
      alert("abcdefgh");
    }

}
```

Comment: Terrible solution. Ever heard of `setTimeout`?